# Regular Expression to match TextMate Variable in for VScode Snippets

Tags: regex, vscode-extensions, textmate

### Background

- Hi all, I'm wokring on a VScode extension for snippets. I highlighted all `$name` TextMate style variables like `$CURRENT_YEAR` and `$TM_FILENAME_BASE`.

  `name` in `$name` can be a integer, or a static variable.
- I would also like to highlight variables like `${<INTEGER>:<DEFAULT>}`, `${<INTEGER>:<DEFAULT>|<OPTIONAL_OPTIONS>}`
  e.g. `${2:placeholder}` and `${1:true|false}`
- Moreover, highlight transformed variables `${<STATIC_VAR>\<MATCH_REGEX>\<TRANSFORM_TARGET>\}`. Example: `${TM_FILENAME/[\\.]/_/` replaces the first `.` with `_`.
- All these example can be found in [VScode documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets#_variables)
- I played [Regex Golf](https://alf.nu/RegexGolf) a little, but I couldn't solve the "Balance" Chapter

### Question

Is there a NEAT way to match all TextMate variables([see definition in chapter 7.2](https://macromates.com/manual/en/snippets#variables)) with a Regular Expression (or other technique)?

In detail, I would want my Regex to match all `$<NAME>`, `${<INTEGER>:<DEFAULT>|<OPTION>}`, and `${<STATIC_VAR>\<MATCH_REGEX>\<TRANSFORM_TARGET>\}`

where

- `<NAME>` can be digits and some specific letters like `LINE_COMMENT`;
- `<DEFAULT>` and  can be any text.
- `<STATIC_VAR>` is some specific letters like `LINE_COMMENT`
- `<MATCH_REGEX>` A regular expression, I'm not going to check if it is legal.
  `<TRANSFORM_TARGET>` The regular expression substitution output, not going to check.

My idea was to detect if there is a pair of brackets (curly parentheses). And the first word after parentheses opening is a `<NAME>`.

TextMate uses [Oniguruma regular expression library by K. Kosako](https://github.com/kkos/oniguruma)

### What I've done

- Match variable without `{}` with

```
match:"\\$(?:[0-9]+|TM_SELECTED_TEXT|<TYPED_ALL_POSSIBLE_NAMES>|TM_CURRENT_WORD|LINE_COMMENT)"
```

- Tried [regex pattern generator (AI)](http://regex.inginf.units.it/demo.html)
- In question [Regular expression to match balanced parentheses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/546433/regular-expression-to-match-balanced-parentheses) is it said not possible in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46334384/16223122)
- Using a dirty work-around

```
\\$(?= (?=<ALL_NAMES>)|{(?=<ALL_NAMES>):.+} )
```

Where `<ALL_NAMES>` represents all `<NAME>`s joined with pipe char `|`

Comment: It is not quite clear what the issue is with your "dirty" regex. What about `[$](\{)?\w+(?(1)(?:\/.*})?)` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/N0NlPS/1))?

Comment: Yes! I just test it and it works beautifully. Before I worked with [regexr](regexr.com) and I knew nothing about "group conditional". By the way, your code did match the transformation but not the default value like `${1:OPT1|OPT2}`, please consider add a `:` like this `[$](\{)?\w+(?(1)(?:[\/:].+})?)` ([new demo](https://regex101.com/r/88xrY5/1))and answer the question so we can close it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a conditional construct here:

```rb
[$](\{)?\w+(?(1)(?:[\/:].*})?)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/N0NlPS/2).

*Details*:

- `[$]` - a `$` char
- `(\{)?` - an optional capturing group with ID = 1 that matches a `{` char
- `\w+` - one or more word chars
- `(?(1)(?:[\/:].*})?)` - a conditional construct: if Group 1 matched, matches an optional sequence of a `/` or `:` and then any zero or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible up to the rightmost occurrence of a `}` char.

Comment: Sorry that I made a mistake in the code `(?(1)(?:[\/:].*})?)` because there should be at least 1 char after the `:` or `/`. I'm accepting this answer but I made a HUGE mistake while describing the question ... So I'm editing this question now. Please consider edit the answer accordingly. I'll finish it in <10min.

Comment: The [conditional group](https://regex101.com/library/hP7hM9) used here did solve most of my question and it works correctly in `.tmLanguage.json` for VScode.

Comment: @Pablion Yes, your question is a bit hectic.So, one char must be there after `/` or `:`? Then replace `.*` with `.+`.

Comment: Feels like I squeezed too many questions in one question. So I rewrite the question to make it clearer. Huge appreciation again.

Answer (score 0):

### Credit to [Wiktor Stribiżew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3832970/wiktor-stribi%C5%BCew)

### The regular expression

[Test demo with explanation](https://regex101.com/r/gxcOY5/1)

```regex
[$]([{])?([0-9]+)?(?(2)|(?:TM_FILENAME))(?(1)(?(2)[:].+|[\/].+[\/].*[\/])})
```

### What does this regex do:

- Match all these (legal vscode snippet variables):

```
$1
$21
${1:default}
${1:default|option}
$TM_FILENAME
${TM_FILENAME/[\.]/_/}
${TM_FILENAME/a//}
```

- And match NONE of these:

```
${1:}
${TM_FILENAME:a|b}
${TM_FILENAME/}
${TM_FILENAME/a/}
${TM_FILENAME//abc/}
${TM_FILENAME/a//a}
```

### full `.tmLanguage.json` fomat code

```
"match": "[$]({)?([0-9]+)?(?(2)|(?:TM_SELECTED_TEXT|TM_CURRENT_LINE|TM_CURRENT_WORD|TM_LINE_INDEX|TM_LINE_NUMBER|TM_FILENAME_BASE|TM_FILENAME|TM_DIRECTORY|TM_FILEPATH|RELATIVE_FILEPATH|CLIPBOARD|WORKSPACE_NAME|WORKSPACE_FOLDER|CURRENT_YEAR_SHORT|CURRENT_YEAR|CURRENT_MONTH_NAME_SHORT|CURRENT_MONTH_NAME|CURRENT_MONTH|CURRENT_DATE|CURRENT_DAY_NAME_SHORT|CURRENT_DAY_NAME|CURRENT_HOUR|CURRENT_MINUTE|CURRENT_SECONDS_UNIX|CURRENT_SECOND|RANDOM|RANDOM_HEX|UUID|BLOCK_COMMENT_START|BLOCK_COMMENT_END|LINE_COMMENT))(?(1)(?(2)[:].+|[/].+[/].*[/])})",
```

### Test in VSCode

[image]